# How can I use an installer variable on the same screen it's input on

Tags: java, install4j

How can I get the the information that's entered into a screen while still on the same screen? For example, suppose I've got a text field that sets a variable called `myVar` and a button *on the same screen* that needs the value of `myVar` to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1) Your button action script can persist the input on all form components as its first action. To do that call

```
formEnvironment.saveFormComponents();
```

Then context.getVariable("myVar") will return the value that is entered on the same screen.

2) You directly access the form component in the action script of the button:

```
String text = ((JTextField)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("123").
                  getConfigurationObject()).getText();
```